# Security update for git on mac

Tags: macos, git

The latest git installers linked to from http://git-scm.com/download/mac all seem to be for snow-leopard `http://sourceforge.net/projects/git-osx-installer/files/git-2.2.1-intel-x86_64-snow-leopard.dmg/download`

I'm using a mac 10.9.3 (which I believe is Mountain Lion). How do I obtain the security update for git (the need for which is described here http://wptavern.com/critical-git-vulnerability-patched-update-your-git-clients-immediately)

Comment: I think the snow leopard here just means that it was built or using the SDK for SL it will work on new versions of the OS

Answer (score 3):

For GitHub client for Mac, you have two options to get the latest version:

- [Download from GitHub](https://mac.github.com).
- Open GitHub app and go to Check for updates.

If you install the command line `git` through homebrew you have to type the following in your terminal:

```
brew update
brew upgrade
```

Apple command line `git` is on `git version 1.9.3 (Apple Git-50)` and there is no update available for the moment.

[This is the official post from GitHub announcing the vulnerability](https://github.com/blog/1938-git-client-vulnerability-announced).