# What to do about recent remote code execution vulnerability in git (on El Capitan)

Tags: macos, security, git

The recent [remote code execution](http://seclists.org/oss-sec/2016/q1/645) bug in git looks pretty serious. The way I read this is that if I'm running a git client prior to 2.7.1, I'm susceptible to remote code execution if I use git to interact with a malicious (or compromised) repo. It seems like a manual upgrade of the git client is in order, but rootless prevents things like brew from working. (I'm currently on the latest stable Xcode 7.2.1)

What's the best way forward under El Capitan? Turn off rootless and install with brew?
Install an updated git client from source? (latest stable binary appears to be prior to 2.7.1)
Is there an updated git client in a newer version of Xcode?

Comment: Could you edit this to narrow down what you seek to do? Remove the git client binary? Put a new one in your path? What is your setup. Are you serving git repos? Using Xcode? Or are you just looking for someone to say that out of box ElCapitan don't listen to git and aren't hackable?

Comment: Updated. Current stable git client (in xcode and stable binary from git-scm) appears to be prior to 2.7.1 and has a remote code execution vulnerability. Seeking guidance about the best way to manually update the git client to a non vulnerable version under El Capitan.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Wikipedia's definition of RCE is triggering code execution remotely - so using git client to pull code from a malicious repository seems lower than RCE in my book. Nevertheless - assuming you just want to know how to avoid using a vulnerable git client until/if Apple patches it, let's open this for now and see what comes up.

Comment: Homebrew works fine with system integrity protection. See @CD-RUM 's answer and my comment for more details. If you're having trouble, you probably have an old b0rked Homebrew installation that didn't survive the upgrade well (this is particularly likely if you went through the beta programme). In that case, Google for ways to fix your Homebrew as it's probably the cleanest way to maintain this kind of software and manage updates.

Answer (score 3):

If you use Homebrew it's pretty easy:

```
brew upgrade git
which git
=> /usr/local/bin/git
git --version
=> git version 2.7.3
```

Done.

Comment: I don't know why this isn't getting more votes. Homebrew was updated a long time ago now and works fine with Rootless in El Capitan; `/usr/local` and `/Library/Caches/Homebrew` are not protected filesystem locations: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204899 ("Paths and applications that third-party apps and installers can write to include: `/Applications`, `/Library`, `/usr/local`").

Answer (score 2):

Brew doesn't ever work to replace or patch an OS version - it's consciously designed to only put binaries beside those from Apple and not in place of.

If you want to make sure that no program calls Apple's `/usr/bin/git` or you don't call it, then these steps will accomplish that goal of hardening your 10.11 installs:

1. Run [OS X Recovery](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT201314) by holding down Command-R while the Mac is starting up.
2. Use the Utilities menu to run Terminal
3. `csrutil disable`
4. reboot
5. Enter single user mode by holding Command-S while the Mac is restarting.
6. `mount -uw /`
7. rm /usr/bin/git
8. halt
9. Repeat the OS X Recovery step and open Terminal and run `csrutil enable`
10. reboot

At this point, the `git` from Apple is removed.

Search for other `git` binaries:

- `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/git` is 2.5.4
- `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/git` is 2.5.4

You are at very slight risk since you only ran without SIP in single user mode long enough to remove the one binary. You can also get git 2.7.4 from brew as of March 18, 2016 if you like:

```
brew install git
git --version
```

You'll want to watch all OS X updates to be sure they don't pop another copy of `git` that's patched lower than you wish. For most people, I would focus on only connecting to servers that are patched and/or known to be not malicious. Just having the git sitting there is low risk in my read of the situation.

Some other threads of interest:

- [Use downloaded Git instead of preinstalled Git](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/138856/use-downloaded-git-instead-of-preinstalled-git)
- [Security update for git on mac](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/162681/security-update-for-git-on-mac)
- [How to properly update git on mac?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/93002/how-to-properly-update-git-on-mac)

Comment: Does Xcode search in `/usr/local/bin` at all?

Comment: I can test that @patrix in a bit. My recollection is that it packages it's own git, so perhaps someone that wants to eviscerate all old git binaries needs to search more thoroughly than just in `/usr/bin`. Specifically the current command line tools have `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/git`at 2.5.4

Comment: So to protect a developer system these git binaries need to be replaced as well I assume (there is `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/git` and `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/libexec/git-core/git` in Xcode, also tools like Github.app or SourceTree.app include their own `git`). So protecting a system will require more than just disabling `/usr/bin/git`.

Comment: I've found `ls -dl $(locate 'git' | grep '/git$')` useful to find the various `git`'s in the system.

Comment: Yup @patrix - it's a bit of a zoo with git being embedded in lots of places. I could easily see people with half a dozen versions between brew, Apple and a couple of utilities to visualize git repos.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any workflow wherein other tools are calling git so I'm ok with simply installing a patched version and using that.

I did the following:

- Cloned from the [official git repo](https://github.com/git/git/)
- Installed with `make && make install`
- And prepended ~/bin to my path in .profile

That should work fine for me I think.

As for only interacting with trusted sources --sure, that's ideal, but there's no excuse to use a known vulnerable piece of software. There are plenty of examples of trusted sources getting compromised. Having a `git clone` actually able to execute arbitrary code is undesirable in my view.